# Wordpress - Jetpack Infinite Scroll, comments form no appear

Tags: ajax, wordpress, comments, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I use Jetpack Infinite Scroll: http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/

On first page comments work good, but when I scroll down and next page is loaded comments no appear.

My loop:

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php comments_template();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How load comments form on next pages after ajax load? I suspect i need a javascript callback.